VBA Backreferencing using Regular Expressions Find and Replace
I want to standardize the formatting of some text within a Word document using VBA and regEx. For example, my document would contain text strings such as "Qty #", "Qty (#)", "QTY(#)", "qty of (#)", etc where # is an integer value from 0-99. My objective is to standardize these strings into the format: "QTY (#)".
Below is the code I have attempted; however, instead of backreferencing the number it inserts a literal "$1" within the parentheses. I've done some research and it appears that the Range.Find doesn't support backreferences. Is there another method that works?
Sub StandardizeQuantityFormat()
    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   
    ' Define the regular expression pattern to match various quantity formats.
    regEx.Pattern = "Qty\s+(\d{1,2})|Qty\s+\((\d{1,2})\)|QTY\((\d{1,2})\)|qty of\s+\((\d{1,2})\)"
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Global = True
   
    ' Define the desired format to replace found patterns.
    Dim replacementFormat As String
    replacementFormat = "QTY ($1)"
   
    ' Access the document's content.
    Dim docContent As Range
    Set docContent = ActiveDocument.Content
   
    ' Execute the Find and Replace using the RegExp.
    Dim match As Object
    For Each match In regEx.Execute(docContent.Text)
        With docContent.Find
            .Text = match.Value ' The text to find
            .Replacement.Text = replacementFormat
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False ' Make sure to set Format to False to avoid formatting issues
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next match

    Set regEx = Nothing
    MsgBox "Quantity formats have been standardized."
End Sub


It appears there may have been a misunderstanding in utilizing the Word replacement feature instead of the RegExp (Regular Expression) replacement method.
Option Explicit

Sub StandardizeQuantityFormat()
    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   
    ' Define the regular expression pattern to match various quantity formats.
    regEx.Pattern = "Qty\s*(?:of\s+)*\(*(\d{1,2})\)*"
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True
    regEx.Global = True
     
    ' Access the document's content.
    Dim docContent As Range
    Set docContent = ActiveDocument.Content
   
    ' Execute the Find and Replace using the RegExp.
    Dim match As Object
    For Each match In regEx.Execute(docContent.Text)
        With docContent.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = match.Value ' The text to find
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.Text = regEx.Replace(match.Value, "QTY ($1)")
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False ' Make sure to set Format to False to avoid formatting issues
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next match

    Set regEx = Nothing
    MsgBox "Quantity formats have been standardized."
End Sub




Thanks for your response. This method does indeed work; however, only if the quantity numbers are unique (such as 11,12,13,14). However, my document contains dozens of instances of the same quantity numbers. When I run the script, instead of replacing "qty (4)" with "QTY (4)" it replaces it with "QTY (4)QTY (4)QTY(4)" (if there were three instances of that number regardless of format). It also replaces valid text such as "QTY (5)" with "QTY (5)" which may be contributing to the overall repeating issue.
